# Взаимодействие и захват картинки из другого приложения

Tags: android, opencv, искусственный-интеллект, бот

Всем доброго времени суток, 
Начал JFF изучать инскуственные интеллекты на агентах. 
Для тренировки с ИИ и opencv пишу бота, целью стала одна игра на андроид. 
Есть ли возможность вытащить картинку с экрана, рендерящуюся этой игрой и послать фейковое нажатие? 
Root есть, XPosed стоит. 
Захват в каждом кадре не нужен, только по событиям бота (захват, принятие решения, проверка, захват...)

С эмулятором возиться ой как не хочется.
К слову, мозги уже готовы, натасканы на  скриншотах, осталось вживить)

Как это сделать, какие методы использовать?
Если просто покажете куда копать - будет уже отлично)